# Confirm dialog causes IE to crash

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I've got a web app using ASP.NET with C# code behind using JQuery 11.1.2. I have a dropdownlist that is populated by an AJAX call to the server when it is clicked. The web method returns a list of options to include in the dropdown based on args. Some of the options return a 'confirm' appended to the end of the option, which my success function splits out of it and I use it on my front end to decide whether or not the option requires confirmation once selected. All good.

My problem occurs when the confirm dialog comes up, it crashes IE 11 no matter the chosen option. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but crashes every time in IE. My only thought is that IE doesn't like that this is all done in an AJAX success function? Not sure. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

```
$('.lazy-load').click(function (e, k) {
        if (e.currentTarget.length < 2) {
            var callerId = getTarget(e);
            callerId = callerId.id;
            // parse out the true encrypted id
            var encIdIndex = callerId.indexOf('ddlAction') + 9;
            var encId = callerId.substring(encIdIndex);
            if (encId == '' || encId == null)
                return;
            // get the valid workflow options for this clientice
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'LandingSummary.aspx/GetWorkflowOptions',
                async: false,
                data: "{ 'csId': '{0}'}".format(encId),
                success: function (data) {
                    ddlId = 'ddlAction' + encId;
                    $$(ddlId).get(0).options.length = 0; // clear
                    $$(ddlId).get(0).options[0] = new Option("Choose...", '');
                    $.each(data.d, function(index, item) {
                        if (item.Value.indexOf('CONFIRM') != -1) {
                            //strip text
                            var newText = item.Value.slice(0, 0 - 'CONFIRM'.length);
                            // add confirm attribute
                            var option = new Option(newText, item.Key);
                            option.setAttribute('data-confirm', 'confirm');
                            $$(ddlId).get(0).options[$$(ddlId).get(0).options.length] = option;
                        }
                        else {
                            $$(ddlId).get(0).options[$$(ddlId).get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Value, item.Key);
                        }
                    });
                    var fullId = $$(ddlId)[0].id;
                    ExpandSelect(fullId);
                    // add warning hookup
                    $$(ddlId).change(function () {
                        var confirmAttribute = $$(ddlId).find('option:selected').attr('data-confirm');
                        //debugger;
                        if (confirmAttribute != undefined) {
                            var newState = $$(ddlId).find('option:selected').text();
                            var sure = confirm('Are you sure you want to move this authorization to the {0} state?'.format(newState));
                            if (!sure) {
                                $$(ddlId).val('');
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert('error retrieving workflow options');
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    })

    function getTarget(obj) {
        var targ;
        var e = obj;
        if (e.target != undefined) targ = e.target;
        else if (e.srcElement != undefined) targ = e.srcElement;
        if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
            targ = targ.parentNode;
        return targ;
    }

});
```

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: IEXPLORE.EXE
  Application Version:  11.0.9600.17631
  Application Timestamp:    54b31a70
  Fault Module Name:    MSHTML.dll
  Fault Module Version: 11.0.9600.17631
  Fault Module Timestamp:   54b33039
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0008d910
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Comment: Side note: I'm sure there must be other ways to have this dialog sent over besides adding it to the select options. It looks like a massive code smell.

Comment: I'm sure there are, but this was written by someone about 3 years ago and I'm not trying to rewrite this whole thing, just wanted to see if there was a simple fix to this issue. If not my solution is to remove the confirm dialog...thank you though.

Comment: `async: false` is a really bad practice and is being deprecated by browser vendors and by jQuery. It blocks the whole page until request is done and has been very much discouraged for many years. As for processing in success callback the concept is standard practice and is not your issue in of itself.

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for your comment. I understand that async false is not a good practice. This app has been in development for over 4 years and I was just handed it after the consultant who was working on it left. We have a soft release date of Aug 4th, so I am very limited with time, hoping to find a quick fix for this, get it to prod and then fix the MANY issues with the app. Thanks again.

Comment: worth removing that option and might help

Comment: Removed, didn't change anything...but I will keep async: false out.

Comment: So, this works...if I put the confirm dialog in a "dummy" ajax call....weird, but oh well.